"PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.RQSCRIPTCREATE' must be declared" error when creating an embedded R script in oml4r
I’m getting this error when trying to create an embedded R script using oml4r,
# Create a public script, available to any user.
> ore.scriptCreate("GLBGLM",
+                  function(data, formula, ...) 
+                    glm(formula = formula, data = data, ...),
+                  global = TRUE,
+                  overwrite=TRUE)
Error in ore.scriptCreate("GLBGLM", function(data, formula, ...) glm(formula = formula,  : 
  Error in .oci.GetQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
  ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.RQSCRIPTCREATE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Help: https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-06550/

This is the script I was trying,
     ore.scriptCreate("GLBGLM",
                 function(data, formula, ...) 
                   glm(formula = formula, data = data, ...),
                 global = TRUE,
                 overwrite=TRUE)

